# Ember.js: ObjectControllers not found

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit

I think I have everything in place. But however I  cannot use `needs: ['shipping', 'checkout'] in the payment controller as they are simply not found, see this error:

```
Error while loading route: Error: <appkit@controller:article/payment::ember1670> needs [ controller:checkout, controller:shipping ] but they could not be found
```

The fun part is, I have visited those routes earlier because it is part of my checkout process. Take a look at the router:

```
    this.resource('articles', {path: '/product'}, function() { // to fill the articles navigation slider
        this.resource('article', {path: '/:article_id'}, function() { // article information slider
            // (...)
            // we have always an active article, thats why the shipping is underneath 'article'
            this.route('shipping', {path: '/verzending'});
            this.route('checkout', {path: '/betaalwijze'});
            this.route('payment', {path: '/afrekenen'});
        });
    });
```

So I visit: `shipping` then `checkout` and then `payment` and get the error. The controllers for those are all ObjectControllers.

Folder structure:

[image: Folder structure]

In the shipping controller I use `needs` to include an ArrayController which does work. Maybe it has to that those are ObjectControllers?

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Edit: to make them `Ember.Controller` does not have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question: [Observes other childcontroller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635782/observes-other-childcontroller)

The state of an ObjectController seems to not live long.