# Observes other childcontroller?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to observe another childcontroller.

I have the following router:

```
this.resource('generics', {path: '/gens'}, function() {
    this.resource('generic', {path: '/:generic_id'}, function() {  
        this.route('prepare'); // Objectcontroller
        this.route('sent'); // Objectcontroller
    });
});
```

I have an observer in the sent controller, however it does not work. I have currently: 'controllers.sent.id' to get the id prepared in the prepare controller. 
If I do a `needs` property with `generic.prepare`. It shows this error:

```
#needs must not specify dependencies with periods in their names (generic.sent)
```

I have also tried to use setupController to add the id to the sent controller properties, however the observer is worthless then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be `genericPrepare`, but `prepare`/`sent` should never exist at the same time.  You'd probably be better off sending the object to `generic` and then having `sent` grab the property off of it.  Why are you against setting it up during `setupController`?  The route will always hit `setupController` of `sent` before it's visible to the end user.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that an ObjectController does not 'lives' in the app. I now do use the setupController to grap those properties.